# Clearing float in cascaded floating elements

Tags: css, css-float

In an cascaded floated elements layout; when I try to clear float for inside element, It expands elements height to cover outer floating elements size. Here is the sample:

```
<div class="right">
    right
</div>
<div class="left">
    <div class="top">
        <span>top</span>
        <div class="right-float-inside">right-float-inside</div>
        <div class="clear-float"></div>
    </div>
    left
</div>
```

corresponding css

```
div {
    padding: 5px;
}
.top {
    background-color: #ee0;
}
.left {
    background-color: #e00;
    margin-right: 200px;
}
.right {
    background-color: #0e0;
    float: right;
    height: 80px;
    width: 200px;
}
.right-float-inside {
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #00e;
}
.clear-float {
    clear: both;
}
```

[image: output]

Here is the live example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/UUpaP/4/

What I'm expecting to get was yellow div ending just after blue div. What I got is yellow div ending after green one.

How can I limit scope of clear?

Comment: Which floats are you trying to clear exactly?

Comment: right float of div with class .right-float-inside

Comment: What you need is `overflow: hidden` for your `.left` element. [working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IKybC)

Comment: thanks @nd_macias it fixed the issue. Would you like to write it as answer so I can approve the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `overflow: hidden` for your `.left` element. [working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IKybC)